# Detect bullet holes on the target image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to know how to detect the bullet holes on the target using Python and OpenCV.

I'm not able to draw the contours around them. So far I have applied a threshold, and I have the following result (Image after threshold and binary AND): [image]

And here's the original image: [image]

I don't know which approach I should follow to detect the bullet holes and calculate the scores accordingly.

Comment: have you considered feature detection?

Comment: I don't know if that's the case, but if the picture is taken from almost the same angle all times, you could consider a subtraction from a clean target image, it would give you a much cleaner image to process

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may simply use a very simple type of segmentation technique, known as `Color Segmentation` in which you threshold the given RGB image to get a binary image as :

```
img = cv2.imread('/Users/anmoluppal/Desktop/cAMDX.jpg')

img_thresholded = cv2.inRange(img, (60, 60, 60), (140, 140, 140))
```

[image]

The noise of the binary image can be removed using the opening operation on the binary image as :

```
kernel = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img_thresholded, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```

[image]

Now you have somewhat a clear picture of the bullet holes, the last part is to find these contours and draw some circle/ Rectangle around them to highlight the foreground area as:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print len(contours)

for contour in contours:
    (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    radius = int(radius)
    cv2.circle(img,center,radius,(0,255,0),2)
    # labelling the circles around the centers, in no particular order.
    position = (center[0] - 10, center[1] + 10)
    text_color = (0, 0, 255)
    cv2.putText(img, str(i + 1), position, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, text_color, 3)
```

[image]

Comment: This works awesome. Is there any way to label these circles?

Comment: Edited, @varsha_holla

Comment: But could I read the size of the shot group given I had a known length of an object in the photo as well (ref. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) for reference? In this case, measure the distance between shot #2 and #6, but the shots furthest apart would have to be identified automatically.

Comment: How would we recognize shots fired in the exact same location as one of the previous shots?

Comment: Hi @BrandonPillay if the bullets exactly overlap, then it would be very difficult to detect with the given context. However, if the bullets are partially overlapping, then we can make an educated guess by judging the contour shapes. We could use the contour area to flag the bullets which have area above a threshold and label them accordingly.