# How to detect bullet holes on the target using Android Opencv

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

I am working in a project where I have to scan the target and recognize the holes in the target and have to score according to the shots. I am not aware of the exact code how to recognize the holes in the target. I imported the opencv library and gone through a program where if I touch it will recognize the corresponding color. Now I am stuck in the coding part. Here is the screenshot of the target sheet that is given to me.

[image]

Could anyone please help me how to proceed further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could find the same problem in another question but it was using in python. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321303/how-to-detect-bullet-holes-on-the-target-using-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what You want You should:

```
1) find white areas with max brightness;
2) find bounding contours of areas with max brightness (from p.1);
3) find bounding boxes for contours from p.2;
4) count bounding boxes.
```

and also take into account some special cases, like "twin" holes in your image.

To implement that steps on Android easiest way is to use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org). How to add it to your project well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35135495/6950238) (You should do some work to do to it: download SDK from [here](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) and add it correctly). Then You should take a look at some tutorial about using OpenCV in Android, for example, [official](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html). And than, You can use code like this (your image added to `drawable` folder of demo project as `target.png`):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Button mProcessButton;

    private Mat mSourceImageMat;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.target_image_view);
        mProcessButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.process_button);
        mProcessButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mProcessButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                processImage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void processImage() {
        try {
            mSourceImageMat = Utils.loadResource(this, R.drawable.target);
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mSourceImageMat.cols(), mSourceImageMat.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            final Mat mat = new Mat();
            final List<Mat> channels = new ArrayList<>(3);

            mSourceImageMat.copyTo(mat);

            // split image channels: 0-H, 1-S, 2-V
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
            Core.split(mat, channels);
            final Mat frameV = channels.get(2);

            // find white areas with max brightness
            Imgproc.threshold(frameV, frameV, 245, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

            // find contours
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            Imgproc.findContours(frameV, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            // find average contour area for "twin" hole detection
            double averageArea = 0;
            int contoursCount = 0;
            Iterator<MatOfPoint> each = contours.iterator();
            while (each.hasNext()) {
                averageArea += Imgproc.contourArea(each.next());
                contoursCount++;
            }
            if (contoursCount != 0) {
                averageArea /= contoursCount;
            }

            int holesCount = 0;
            each = contours.iterator();
            while (each.hasNext()) {
                MatOfPoint contour = each.next();

                MatOfPoint2f areaPoints = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
                RotatedRect boundingRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(areaPoints);
                Point rect_points[] = new Point[4];

                boundingRect.points(rect_points);
                for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){
                    Imgproc.line(mSourceImageMat, rect_points[i], rect_points[(i+1)%4], new Scalar(255,0,0), 2);
                }
                holesCount++;

                Imgproc.putText(mSourceImageMat, Integer.toString(holesCount), new Point(boundingRect.center.x + 20, boundingRect.center.y),
                        Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5 ,new  Scalar(255, 0, 0));

                // case of "twin" hole (like 9 & 10) on image
                if (Imgproc.contourArea(contour) > 1.3f * averageArea) {
                    holesCount++;
                    Imgproc.putText(mSourceImageMat, ", " + Integer.toString(holesCount), new Point(boundingRect.center.x + 40, boundingRect.center.y),
                            Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5 ,new  Scalar(255, 0, 0));
                }

            }

            // convert to bitmap:
            Utils.matToBitmap(mSourceImageMat, bm);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

            // release
            frameV.release();
            mat.release();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mOpenCVLoaderCallback);
    }

    private BaseLoaderCallback mOpenCVLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mProcessButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } break;
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And if You press `FIND HOLES` `Button` You get result like this

[image: result]

For other images You should adjust `245, 255` values in

```
Imgproc.threshold(frameV, frameV, 245, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
```

line.

Update: `MainActivity` layout (`activity_main.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/target_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/target"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/process_button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/process_button"
        android:text="Find holes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andriy Omelchenko. Your program works like a charm. I just followed your steps and it works great. Really you are so helpful. I am just a fresher started my carrier as an android developer. This is my first project on Image processing. So I do not have any idea about it. Still I have many milestones to complete. Any way thanks a lot for your guidance. You are so helpful. I wish I could learn more things from you sir. Thank you sir.

Comment: You are welcome! (and also You can upvote the answer ;) )

Comment: Hello @Andriy Omelchenko, I need another help from you. I hope you can help me in this. Your example works for single image that is stored in a drawable  folder. So suppose if I want to capture an image and recognize the holes means what should I do? Could you please help me with the coding part. Now I want to capture an image and when I click the "Find holes" button I should be able to recognize the holes. Is there a way to do it? Please I hope you can help me fix the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Easiest way - get picture from `Camera` via intent, like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6449092) by [barmaley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/472270/barmaley). And You can get `bitmap` with picture this way `bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mImageUri);` Then just replace `mSourceImageMat = Utils.loadResource(this, R.drawable.target);` with `Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mSourceImageMat);`.