# Detecting Drill Holes and tapering in manufactured product using python

Tags: python, opencv, detection, grayscale, hough-transform

I would like to detect drill holes and tapering in this product

[image: Original Image]

The drill holes are circled lying on the circular boundary. The red circle at the bottom is where the tapering is to be detected.

[image: What is to be detected]

I have tried using Hough circles to detect the drill holes

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('DSC_1257.JPG',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)


circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,300,
                        param1=40,param2=20,minRadius=15,maxRadius=30)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

imS2 = cv2.resize(cimg, (960, 540))
cv2.imshow('detected circles',imS2 )
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This does detect the drill holes but it also detect an additional 7 holes elsewhere which are unwanted.
I want to detect only the two drill holes and nothing more.Could you please tell me a solution for that and for the tapering problem as well

Comment: Hough circles is rules out. This is because your regions of interest do not  appear to be circular at all. You have to find another approach.

Comment: Can you alter the position of the camera or include a known rectangle in the background that could be used to correct the image and make the circles round?

Comment: @JeruLuke I have also tried using color segmentation as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321303/how-to-detect-bullet-holes-on-the-target-using-python                                                                                                               

I wasn't able to narrow it down to only those 2 points!
I am open to any suggestions/solutions!

Comment: But how are the other holes different from the ones that you marked?

Comment: @JeruLuke Pardon, I didn't quite get you. What other holes?
The small ones encircled in red are drill holes,which differ by a smaller area to any other hole i feel!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Umm, basically similar products like this will run through via a conveyor belt where a picture will be taken. The drill holes(when detected) will then be compared to the drill holes on a reference product.
The drill holes(atleast on this product) are only on circular plane where the two marked drill holes are present!
This was just an image of the product.