# OpenCv inRange function behaves differently when called from Objective C++

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I have used the excellent answer to the question here:

[How to detect bullet holes on the target using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321303/how-to-detect-bullet-holes-on-the-target-using-python)

I have verified that it works in both Python 2 and 3.6, but I would like to use the concept in an iOS application written in Objective C(++). This is my attempt at translating it. Ultimately, I need it to work with an image taken by the camera, so I don't want to use imread, but I've checked that this makes no difference.

```
UIImage *nsi = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CANDX.jpg"];
cv::Mat original;
UIImageToMat(nsi, original);

cv::Mat thresholded;
cv::inRange(original, cv::Scalar(40,40,40), cv::Scalar(160,160,160), thresholded);

cv::Mat kernel = cv::Mat::ones(10, 10, CV_64FC1);
cv::Mat opening;
cv::morphologyEx(thresholded, opening, cv::MORPH_OPEN, kernel);

vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours;
cv::findContours(opening, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

The call to inRange, with the same values as the Python version, gives a completely black image. Indeed, it is impossible to pick values for lower- and upper-bounds that do not result in this outcome. I've tried converting the image to HSV and using HSV values for lower- and upper-bound. This makes a slight difference in that I can get some vaguely recognisable outcomes, but nothing like the useful result I should be getting.

If I substitute the 'thresholded' image from the answer and comment out the inRange call, the `morphology` and `findContours` calls work okay.

Am I doing something wrong in setting up the inRange call?

Comment: The original question you refer to does not exist -- did you get the link right?

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek, not sure how I managed to paste it wrongly! Edited now.

Comment: What's the data type of the elements (and number of channels) of the `original` cv::Mat?

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek, the data type of the elements is CV_8UC4, I think, looking at the source of UIImageToMat in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgcodecs/src/ios_conversions.mm. The number of channels is reported in my code as 4.

Comment: Aha, 4 channel image, but your range specifies only values for 3 channels.  My educated guess would be that the code will imply the 4th element of those scalars to be a 0 in both cases, so it looks for pixels with alpha value of 0 (and there are none). I'd have a shot at either dropping the alpha channel (you're taking pictures from camera, so it's kinda irrelevant anyway -- `cv::cvtColor`), or specifying the range using 4-element scalars.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. If you want to write it up as an answer, all I had to do was put `cvtColor(original, original, cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR);` in just before the inRange call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention in the comments, the data type of `original` is `CV_8UC4` -- i.e. it's a 4 channel image. However, in your call to [`cv::inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981), you provide ranges for only 3 channels.

[`cv::Scalar`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d1/da0/classcv_1_1Scalar__.html) represents a 4-element vector. When you call the [constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d1/da0/classcv_1_1Scalar__.html#ae64e021266b9f7661f66a3c77d175c1f) with only 3 values, a default value of 0 is used for the 4-th element.

Hence, your call to `inRange` is actually equivalent to this:

```
cv::inRange(original, cv::Scalar(40,40,40,0), cv::Scalar(160,160,160,0), thresholded);
```

You're looking only for pixels that have the alpha channel set to 0 (fully transparent). Since the image came from a camera, it's highly unlikely there will be any transparent pixels -- the alpha channel is probably just all 255s.

There are 2 options to solve this:

- Drop the unneeded alpha channel. One way to do this is to use [`cv::cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html), e.g.

  ```
  cv::cvtColor(original, original, cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
  ```
- Specify desired range for all the channels, e.g.

  ```
  cv::inRange(original, cv::Scalar(40,40,40,0), cv::Scalar(160,160,160,255), thresholded);
  ```