# How to detect the bullet holes on the target using open cv in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to identify the holes in the target and score them accordingly. I have tried to find contours and it does a lot of work but it did not give me the 100% result. Sometimes it gives me an accurate result and sometimes it misses some bullets. I do not know how to do it. I am new in open CV and image processing. May be its due to the live streaming of the camera and light frequency. Kindly help me to solve this problem.

**Details of my target**

1. top is 6 feet from the ground surface
2. camera is 1 feet from the ground level

**Target image**

[image]

**Image With Holes**

[image]

**Gray Scale Image**

[image]

Here is my code to get video from the camera:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (capture == null)
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            //capture = new Capture(0);
            capture = new Capture("rtsp://admin:admin123@192.168.1.64:554/live.avi");


            capture.ImageGrabbed += Capture_ImageGrabbed;
            capture.Start();
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
        index = 0;
        if (index < panlist.Count)
        {
            panlist[++index].BringToFront();
        }
        CamPnelList[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
        Rifle = true;
    }
    private void Capture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            Mat m = new Mat();
            capture.Retrieve(m);
            imginpt = m.ToImage<Gray, byte>();
            RecImg = m.ToImage<Rgb, byte>();

            if (rec.X != 0 && rec.Y != 0 && CamPnelList[0].BackColor == Color.LightGreen)
            {
                imginpt.ROI = rec;
                RecImg.ROI = rec;
                imgout1 = new Image<Gray, byte>(imginpt.Width, imginpt.Height, new Gray(0));
                imgout1 = imginpt.Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(100), new Gray(255));
                imginpt.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;
                tempimg1 = imgout1.CopyBlank();
                imgout1.CopyTo(tempimg1);
                cam1pictureBox.Image = imgout1.Bitmap;
                //Application.DoEvents();

            }
            else
            {
                cam1pictureBox.Image = imginpt.Bitmap;
            }
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here is how I am extracting contours:

```
    contoursimg1 = new Image<Gray, byte>(tempimg1.Width, tempimg1.Height, new Gray(0));
            Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
            Mat Hier = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.FindContours(tempimg1, contours, Hier, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.Tree, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
            CvInvoke.DrawContours(contoursimg1, contours, -1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Do you have an image of the target with hole?

Comment: Take a look at [How to detect bullet holes on the target using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321303/how-to-detect-bullet-holes-on-the-target-using-python)

Comment: ... and the grayscale version.

Comment: @Fildor i have added the image with holes and a gray scale also.

Comment: Hm, doesn't look that bad, though. Some false positives, some missed. Have you tried working on a diff image? I.e. You take the image without holes, then take the image with holes then subtract and normalize. Should clear out some of the artefacts and false positives. You may have to apply a high-pass filter, also.

Comment: @Fildor yes i have tried that too but the problem is the noise when i subtract the images. i have also tried to filter up but did not get succeed. i dont know how to apply high-filter and the thing is you did not notice the holes on top, there are four holes and in gray scale image there are three. And sometimes it gives four i think its due to the light frequency or the height difference of target and camera.

Comment: I think the lost ones are due to your threshold. I'd do a test: greyscale the image, then binarize it and play with the threshold. Should give you much clearer results.

Comment: Can you add an original pic with holes in a lossless format to play around with?

Comment: @Fildor the Second pic is the original one with holes

Comment: Yes but jpeg. You are not actually working on jpeg are you? Aaaaouugh ... I just saw you get the images from a .avi ... ok ...

Comment: no i am just capturing the image from a live cam using emgu cv and applying the Findcontours method to find holes.

Comment: You need to increase your threshold to like `130-140` to get more accurate results

Comment: The accuracy of these algorithms depend on the values you give to them. They will never be 100%. Even you can not be 100%. You are just comparing the algorithm output with your eyes. It is not fair. If you want a method which will be even **more** accurate than you, then you need to create a neural network and train it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a few similar projects using video as a source and when the target objects have been small but a fairly well defined size the I've taken the difference between frames and used blob detection which is a good fast algorithm to use when dealing with real-time video. I noticed the perspective seems to have changed a little between your two example shots so rather than do that I tried the following code:

```
const int blobSizeMin = 1;
const int blobSizeMax = 5;
var white = new Bgr(255, 255, 255).MCvScalar;

Mat frame = CvInvoke.Imread(@"e:\temp\Frame.jpg", ImreadModes.Grayscale);
Mat mask = CvInvoke.Imread(@"e:\temp\Mask.jpg", ImreadModes.Grayscale);
frame.CopyTo(frame = new Mat(), mask);
CvInvoke.BitwiseNot(frame, frame);
CvInvoke.Threshold(frame, frame, 128, 255, ThresholdType.ToZero);
var blobs = new Emgu.CV.Cvb.CvBlobs();
var blobDetector = new Emgu.CV.Cvb.CvBlobDetector();
Image<Gray, Byte> img = frame.ToImage<Gray, Byte>();
blobDetector.Detect(img, blobs);
int bulletNumber = 0;
foreach (var blob in blobs.Values)
{
    if (blob.BoundingBox.Width >= blobSizeMin && blob.BoundingBox.Width <= blobSizeMax
        && blob.BoundingBox.Height >= blobSizeMin && blob.BoundingBox.Height <= blobSizeMax)
    {
        bulletNumber++;
        Point textPos = new Point((int) blob.Centroid.X - 1, (int) blob.Centroid.Y - 1);
        CvInvoke.PutText(frame, bulletNumber.ToString(), textPos, FontFace.HersheyPlain, 
            fontScale: 1, color: white);
    }
}
CvInvoke.Imwrite(@"e:\temp\Out.png", frame);
```

It inverts the frame so the holes are white, discards values below 50% and then does blob detection only taking notice of blobs with a size between one and five pixels. That was close to working but picked up a few extra points at the top left & right and bottom-left that look pretty similar to bullet holes to the eye as well. What I've done in the past that works well when you mount the camera in a fixed location is to have a black & white mask image to remove anything outside the area of interest:

**Mask.jpg**

[image: Mask image]

Once that was added I detected a total of 21 bullet holes which looks correct:

**Out.png**

[image: Bullet detection results]

But assuming you're detecting the shots in real-time I think you should have good luck with looking at the difference between frames and that should remove the need to use a mask image. Take a look at the `CvInvoke.Subtract` method, from some existing code you can use something like the following:

```
CvInvoke.Subtract(frame, lastFrame, diff);
CvInvoke.CvtColor(diff, gray, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
CvInvoke.Threshold(gray, gray, detectThreshold, 255, ThresholdType.ToZero);
```