# better way to find bullet holes in a target

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

Hi I'm making a project about detecting bullet holes in target circles. My original idea was to use Hough circle algorithms to detect both targets which works quite alright for photos that are straight in front of it and bullet holes that are not as good. Sooo I was wandering if anyone could tip me with some better solution on finding them or helping me improve this code.

```py
import cv2 as cv   
import numpy as np 
import math 
import sys
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

MAX_POINTS = 10

def main(argv):

    default_file = 'tarczamala.jpg'
    default_size = 600, 600

    im = Image.open(default_file)
    im = im.resize(default_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im.save('600' + default_file)

    filename = argv[0] if len(argv) > 0 else '600' + default_file
    # Loads an image
    src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(filename), cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
    # Check if image is loaded fine
    if src is None:
        print ('Error opening image!')
        print ('Usage: hough_circle.py [image_name -- default ' + default_file + '] \n')
        return -1

    # skala szarości
    gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.imshow('gray', gray)

    # Bilateral
    bilateral = cv.bilateralFilter(gray, 7, 15, 10)
    cv.imshow('bilateral', bilateral)

    blank = np.zeros(bilateral.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')
    cv.imshow('blank', blank)

    # mask = cv.circle(blank, (bilateral.shape[1] // 2, bilateral.shape[0] // 2), 320, 255, -1)
    # cv.imshow('Mask', mask)
    #
    # masked = cv.bitwise_and(bilateral, bilateral, mask=mask)
    # cv.imshow('masked', masked)

    # Edge Cascade
    canny = cv.Canny(bilateral, 50, 175)
    cv.imshow('canny1', canny)

    # ret, tresh = cv.threshold(gray, 125, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    # cv.imshow('tresch', tresh)

    contours, hierarchies = cv.findContours(canny, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    print(f'{len(contours)} contour(s) found')

    # cv.drawContours(blank, contours, -1, (255,0,0), 1)
    # cv.imshow('contours drawn', blank)

    rows = canny.shape[0]

 # Target

    circles = cv.HoughCircles(canny, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 0.01,
                              param1=100, param2=50,
                              minRadius=7, maxRadius=300)

    # print(f'{circles}"')

    biggestCircle = findBiggestCircle(circles)
    # print(f'{biggestCircle} biggest circle')

    mask = cv.circle(blank, (math.floor(biggestCircle[0]), math.floor(biggestCircle[1])), math.floor(biggestCircle[2]), 255, -1)
    cv.imshow('rysowanie granicy', mask)

    masked = cv.bitwise_and(bilateral, bilateral, mask=mask)
    cv.imshow('granice', masked)

    # Edge Cascade
    canny = cv.Canny(masked, 50, 175)
    cv.imshow('canny2', canny)

    if biggestCircle is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

        # print(f'{biggestCircle} biggest circle')

        delta_r = biggestCircle[2] / 10
        biggest_circle_center = [biggestCircle[0], biggestCircle[1]]

        center = (math.floor(biggestCircle[0]), math.floor(biggestCircle[1]))
        # print(f'{center} center')
        # circle center
        cv.circle(src, center, 1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
        # circle outline
        radius = math.floor(biggestCircle[2])
        cv.circle(src, center, radius, (0, 0, 255), 3)



# bullet holes

    hits = cv.HoughCircles(canny, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10,
                           param1=300, param2=10,
                           minRadius=7, maxRadius=10)
    # print(f'{hits}"')

    score = countHitScore(hits.tolist(), delta_r, biggest_circle_center)

    print(f'The score is: {score}"')

    if hits is not None:
        hits = np.uint16(np.around(hits))
        for i in hits[0, :]:
            # print(f'promien trafienia {i[2]}"')
            center = (i[0], i[1])
            # circle center
            cv.circle(src, center, 1, (0, 100, 100), 3)
            # circle outline
            radius = i[2]
            cv.circle(src, center, radius, (255, 0, 255), 3)

    cv.imshow("detected circles", src)
    cv.waitKey(0)

    return 0

def findBiggestCircle(circles):

    # print(f'{circles}')
    listOfCircles = circles[0]
    biggestCircle = listOfCircles[0]

    for circle in listOfCircles:
        # print(f'{circle} circle')
        # print(f'2 {circle}')
        # print(f'3 {biggestCircle}')
        if circle[2] > biggestCircle[2]:
            # print('4')
            biggestCircle = circle
    print(biggestCircle)
    return biggestCircle.tolist()

def countHitScore(hits, delta_r, target_center):
    score = 0
    print(f'{hits} hits')

    for hit in hits[0]:
        # print(f'{hit} hit')
        # print(f'{(target_center)} center')
        x_dist = hit[0] - target_center[0] if hit[0] > target_center[0] else target_center[0] - hit[0]
        y_dist = hit[1] - target_center[1] if hit[1] > target_center[1] else target_center[1] - hit[1]

        total_dist = math.hypot(x_dist, y_dist) - hit[2]

        punkty = math.ceil(total_dist / delta_r)

        if punkty < 1:
            punkty = 1

        score += 11 - punkty

        # print(f'{total_dist / delta_r} math')
        # print(f'{total_dist / delta_r} total_dist / delta_r')
        print(f'{11 - punkty} zdobyte punkty')
        # print(f'{x_dist} x {y_dist} y')

    return score

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, provide your test images.

Comment: I've added two different targets results and one after changing to only contours

Comment: why make your life hard? why not scan the paper with a mild backlight? backlight will shine through holes, while the paper stays dark.

Comment: An alternative to Christoph Rackwitz’s suggestion: Put a high-contrasting material underneath the target circle before photographing it. For example, a green or blue paper. Then use the HSV color space to segment the bullet holes. Also note that we need the original, unprocessed, images to reproduce your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect bullet holes on the target image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321303/detect-bullet-holes-on-the-target-image)

Comment: Well, i was hoping to make usefull on shooting range where u cannot control background

Comment: Is it possible to prepare an image that has not been damaged by gun?
If it is possible, you can consider the way based on image difference.
(Two images will be able to be aligned using a pattern composed of circles and numerical values.)

Comment: I was also thinking about smth like that, to make a addon to co confirm  every hit each time. To compare it to the previous photo.